# How to convert pixels to cm and taking DPI into account?

Tags: javascript

I tried the following code, but it doesn't work, jsfiddle gives me this error message:

```
"<a class='gotoLine' href='#65:11'>65:11</a> Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined"
```

this is the function:

```
 function px2cm(px) {
   var d = $("<div/>").css({ position: 'absolute', top : '-1000cm', left : '-1000cm', height : '1000cm', width : '1000cm' }).appendTo('body');
   var px_per_cm = d.height() / 1000;
   d.remove();
   return px / px_per_cm;
 }
```

Comment: `$` is (usually) jQuery. You don't have jQuery loaded. Therefore `$` is undefined.

Comment: thank you a lot this was very helpful and i could solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

You could easily multiply the amount of pixels against your [DPI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/devicePixelRatio).

```js
const pxToCm = (px) => {
  const PX_IN_CM = 0.026458333;

  return px * window.devicePixelRatio * PX_IN_CM;
}

console.log(pxToCm(1));
```